# How to obtain and use a Bearer token with Fastlane Match and Azure Devops Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, fastlane-match

I have a multi-target/variant React Native project that uses Fastlane to build and deploy it. The focus of this question is iOS-related; specifically, I'm trying to understand how to use Fastlane Match to manage certificates.

I have two repositories in a single Azure DevOps project, one for the code and one for the certificates. I've set up SSH Git access for Azure and, when run locally, am able to use a `git@` URL in my `match` configuration to successfully clone the repo and update certs:

```bash
$ bundle exec fastlane update_certs
...
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:50.94]: Cloning remote git repo...
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:50.94]: If cloning the repo takes too long, you can use the `clone_branch_directly` option in match.
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:50.94]: $ git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/<MY COMPANY>/<PROJECT>/<REPO> /var/folders/_l/5tqpmd_d6x5176yqdp77gr_c0000gp/T/d20240306-8899-1fyv6tu
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:50.96]: ▸ Cloning into '/var/folders/_l/5tqpmd_d6x5176yqdp77gr_c0000gp/T/d20240306-8899-1fyv6tu'...
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.23]: ▸ remote: Azure Repos
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.25]: ▸ remote: Found 14 objects to send. (25 ms)
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.27]: ▸ Receiving objects: 100% (14/14), 17.46 KiB | 17.46 MiB/s, done.
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.28]: $ git --no-pager branch --list origin/master --no-color -r
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.30]: ▸   origin/master
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.30]: Checking out branch master...
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.30]: $ git checkout master
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.31]: ▸ branch 'master' set up to track 'origin/master'.
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.31]: ▸ Switched to a new branch 'master'
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.35]:   Decrypted '<CERT>.cer'
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.35]:   Decrypted '<CERT>.p12'
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.35]:   Decrypted 'AppStore_com.<ID>.mobileprovision'
INFO [2024-03-06 10:12:51.35]:   Successfully decrypted certificates repo
```

If I try the same in an Azure Pipeline the build hangs at the initial clone step.  I've tried including the secrets repository with some `resources: repositories:` YAML, and adding a `InstallSSHKey@0` task to the pipeline that appears to succeed, but neither addition helps.

The [`match` docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/) state that when using Azure I may want to use `bearer` token authentication but don't really offer any more details.

My understanding is that this means to use the equivalent `https://` Git URL, and provide `match` with a `git_bearer_authorization` parameter, like so:

```rb
match(
  type: "appstore",
  app_identifier: <BUNDLE ID>,
  api_key: <API KEY>,
  git_bearer_authorization: <WHAT GOES HERE?>,
  git_url: "https://<ORG>@dev.azure.com/<ORG>/<PROJECT>/_git/<REPO>",
)
```

I've tried creating a Personal Access Token and using that (with and without base64 encoding, with and without the org name Azure suggests after the `https://`, above) but am still asked for username and password. The git command generated by `match` adds a `-c http.extraheader='Authorization: Bearer <CONTENTS OF git_bearer_authorization>` to the git command.

How do I generate a bearer token, and how can I use that locally and in CI? Explicit steps to a working `match` would be really *really* appreciated! Alternatively, has anyone managed to get SSH access (i.e. `git@` URL) working with `match` in an Azure Pipeline, and if so, how?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DevOps https url, and `system.accesstoken` as the bear token in pipeline.

Please check the similar [link](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/21606) for your reference. And existing yaml [here](https://github.com/Amsterdam/amsterdam-app-frontend/blob/8cbefc37e6ce87e6de68d4b2109b1686a7a3f9fa/pipelines/templates/ios-sync.yml#L30).

Comment: Thanks.  I'd seen that link but the YAML example was new to me, and useful.  What actually fixed it was copying the YAML format (`$(System.AccessToken)`) and following the advice about repo access in [this post](https://www.timschaeps.be/post/dealing-with-error-tf401019-submodules-azure-pipelines/).  I'll have to have two separate lanes for local and CI builds but can at least progress now.  Marking as correct since - along with this comment - it helped answer the question.